# Fullcalendar: shrink/expand calendar height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

This is the calendar I have, however, I'd like for it to be shrunk down a bit. When I do this with the following command I get a truncated schedule instead of a compressed one. Take a look:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'height', 200);
                       ---OR WITH---
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'contentHeight', 200);
```

Calendar before resizing with the above command:
[image: Calendar before resizing with the above command:]

Calendar after trying to resize:
[image: Calendar after trying to resize:]

You can see a scrollbar has appeared and some events are no longer present (until I scroll). I have played around with CSS to try resizing it manually (notably with the .fc-slats > table height and #calendar font-size) but these are very hard to work with and create misplaced events when changed dynamically. I need to be able to vertically shrink/expand the calendar dynamically, preferably using JQuery. How can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I´m trying to shrink progressively my calendar scheduler height too when user clicks a button. Is there a way to do this like applying css `zoom: 0.75;` but not using that?

Comment: I've given up on my scheduling application as it was taken over by someone else. I wasn't able to find a good way of fixing this issue reliably. Please post a solution if you find a way, maybe the code base has evolved a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Just add this css to the page you have your calender "DIV"

```
.fc-time-grid .fc-slats td {
  height: 1em;  /* Edit as required */
}
```

Comment: That only shrinks it so much though... Even with height: 0 the calendar is pretty big. I would like to minify it further. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found an unperfect way to "shrink" FullCalendar... It seems to be to only way.

Using CSS `zoom` property, it give a nice result in Chrome 60, Opera 47 and IE 11 *(surprisingly! For once.)*... But sadly, it just do not respond at all in FireFox 55.

[MDN cross-browser compatibility table in the `zoom` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom) is quite out of date... That's why I mention the browsers I tested. Maybe some SO users could tell about Safari and other browsers... Mobiles, etc.

So, I think that is your better option... Or live with a scrollbar *(which could be improve with CSS)*.

In [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/JyQJGN), you can toggle a class to zoom the calendar between 100% and 75%.

```
.shrinked{
  zoom: 0.75;
}
```

Comment: This has been widely depreciated. However it's given me the idea to try out css transforms. Notably scaling. Thanks!

Comment: Using `transform:scale(0.75);`... Yeah it works. Until you have some events in the calendar and notice that they are misplaced (not in the right "cell").