# Fullcalendar: Adjust calendar height to parent div

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to create a calendar that adjust it's size to the parent div without success.
It's working with the Width but not height.

I haven't modified any property of the Fullcalendar lib. I do not want to have fixed height since I want the div/calendar resize to the user screen size.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="div-container">
<div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.div-container{
width: 90%;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 100px!important;
}
```

Comment: The way FullCalendar is built (with absolutely positioned dynamic elements), you just can't change the height. See this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108126/fullcalendar-shrink-expand-calendar-height) about to "shrink" it. You just can play with the width to adjust it.

Comment: I've checked that post and no option is working for me :(. 
I just want to resize the entire div in order to put another items in the page, it's with 100% width 100% height. When I put #calendar{width:50%} it works properly, but not with height

Comment: Again, you just can't change the height. FullCalendar is dynamically rendered based on the width. The only thing you can do (which may be ugly) is to is set `overflow:scroll` to the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fullcalendar has a windowResize callback that according to their docs is:

> Triggered after the calendar's dimensions have been changed due to the
>   browser window being resized.

Given that, and the fact that it has a height property, if you get the height of the div you are looking for, you should be able to do something like this:

```
function get_height() {
      return $(window).height();
}

$('#calendar').fullcalendar({
    height: get_height(),
    windowResize:  function(view) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'height', get_calendar_height());
    },
    [...]
```

Make sure that the selector you use, in this case $(window) actually has a height, or your calendar won't have any height.